# How to use convex lens to magnify image without inverting

Tags: optics, visible-light, refraction, geometric-optics, lenses

From my knowledge, convex lenses magnify and invert light rays that pass through it. So is it possible to use a second convex lens to make the magnified inverted image into a magnified **upright** image?

Comment: Terrestrial telescope? http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/geoopt/teles.html#c2

Comment: @Pieter no. I'm looking for a way to magnify a image (similar to a projector), without inverting it.

Comment: The classical overhead projector then?

Comment: Binoculars do that.